# Why my for looping an index in python not give me correct output

Tags: python

I am new learner for python.I am trying to make a basic login accout check, and somehow, my code is not showing what I want. I have defined three user name, and when I run my code, if the first time I put an incorrect user name, the code show account not exit,but it is not shoing. I do not know why

I believe it is my for loop problem, because when I input a wrong account, my i index start at 0 and keep loop until the end index and compare the input username and the exist username in the list. Then after compare all the index if not found user name, then print account not exist, I try to fix this issue, but not find a correct way.

```
user1=[  
   {'id':'0001','name':'123','password':'a123', 'balance':0.00},
   {'id':'0002','name':'456','password':'a456', 'balance':0.00},  
   {'id':'0003','name':'789','password':'a789', 'balance':0.00}
]

for x in range(0,4):

    name = input('User Name：')
    for i in range(len(user1)):
        if name == user1[i]['name']:  
            password = input('Password：')
            if password == user1[i]['password']:  
                print("Success login")
        continue
        if name != user1[i]['name']:
            print("Account not exist, input new one")
```

If I input wrong user name; it should show account not exist input new one, then I put user name 456 then will ask the correct password.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the logic of your loop body:

```
for i in range(len(user1)):
    if name == user1[i]['name']:  
        password = input('Password：')
        if password == user1[i]['password']:  
            print("Success login")
    continue
    if name != user1[i]['name']:
        print("Account not exist, input new one")
```

Regardless of the input, you will *never* get to the second `if` statement: any time your program gets to that point, you tell it to `continue` with the next loop iteration.  Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(user1)):
    if name == user1[i]['name']:  
        password = input('Password：')
        if password == user1[i]['password']:  
            print("Success login")
        else:
            print("Account not exist, input new one")
```

Note that this will work better if you put the all of the accounts into a single dict, so you can access them directly:

```
user1 = {
   '123': {'id':'0001', 'password':'a123', 'balance':0.00},
   '456': {'id':'0002', 'password':'a456', 'balance':0.00},  
   '789': {'id':'0003', 'password':'a789', 'balance':0.00}
}
```

This allows you to directly access each account by name, rather than searching the entire list for the user trying to log in.

Comment: There is a missing `else` in case of password fail which wouldn't trigger the last `else`. And the OP may learn to simplify the loop with a `for singleUser in user1` instead of `for i in range(len(user1))`

Comment: else:
        print("Account not exist, input new one")   I tried this, but now work well. When I enter first unexist account, it will show 3 times out put "Accout not exist... and after that, enter a correct input will also tell me the account not exist....  I think maybe the first time enter unexist account name, the for loop only check first index, and compare it is not exist, then print account not exist, It not loop all the index if I put a wrong user name at first time...

Comment: I change the indentation, still have a small problem which is I put wrong account name, it does not have any out put. just ask you to input a new user name...I have no idea why it happened,